# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes when trying to do anything with videos

Tags: 18.04, video

Every time I try to open any video that I have on a hard drive, there are signs of loading, then nothing happens, then I have to double click it again and it opens it normally. Also when I do right click on a video and go to properties, it opens properties but then it freezes. Also when I try to access terminal from Applications window, it starts loading then it crashes, but it works fine when I open it with right click anywhere... I have no idea what is going on or how to even start fixing all these issues. Any help please?

`grep -i "error" /var/log/syslog` outputs:

```
Nov  7 00:11:53 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Parent 5254, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (128): Connection reset by peer: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358
Nov  7 00:13:09 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #4] WARNING: Decoder=7f8e0ad86200 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:13:09 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #4] WARNING: Decoder=7f8e0ad86200 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:18:10 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #4] WARNING: Decoder=7f8df668b600 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:18:10 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: message repeated 2 times: [ [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #4] WARNING: Decoder=7f8df668b600 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307]
Nov  7 00:18:10 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #3] WARNING: Decoder=7f8df668b600 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:18:10 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #4] WARNING: Decoder=7f8df668b600 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:18:10 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #4] WARNING: Decoder=7f8df668b600 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:18:10 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #2] WARNING: Decoder=7f8df668b600 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:18:10 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #1] WARNING: Decoder=7f8df668b600 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:18:10 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: message repeated 2 times: [ [Child 7054, MediaPlayback #1] WARNING: Decoder=7f8df668b600 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307]
Nov  7 00:18:23 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Parent 5254, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (259): Connection reset by peer: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358
Nov  7 00:18:26 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Parent 5254, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (111): Connection reset by peer: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358
Nov  7 00:19:41 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7246, MediaPlayback #1] WARNING: Decoder=7f5b40797000 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:19:41 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7246, MediaPlayback #4] WARNING: Decoder=7f5b40797000 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:22:45 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7246, MediaPlayback #1] WARNING: Decoder=7f5b28796200 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
Nov  7 00:22:45 aleksandar-MS-7996 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1651]: [Child 7246, MediaPlayback #3] WARNING: Decoder=7f5b28796200 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-tGfEvD/firefox-68.0.1+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3307
```

`free -h` outputs:

```
 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,8G        4,0G        804M        261M        2,9G        3,4G
Swap:          2,0G        1,0M        2,0G
```

this should be smart data of hdd:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5UHX.jpg

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The output of `dmesg | grep -i "error"` might provide some clues. You might also find something with `grep -i "error" /var/log/syslog` [edit]ing the output of these commands into your post would likely be useful. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: There are many things that could cause your problem. Let's start out simple... edit your question and show me `free -h` and screenshot(s) of the `Disks` application SMART Data of your HDD. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Lets also check your file system for errors. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.

Comment: @heynnema when I boot live USB, I can't access terminal via CTRL + ALT + T, I can only access grub with c. If I run those commandes on installed system on hdd, it is looping 20 times. Which one of those I should provide?

Comment: When you boot to the Ubuntu Live USB, select the "Try Ubuntu" at the GRUB menu. Then follow the other instructions in my prior comment. What applications to you use to view videos? VLC? Firefox? Your HDD SMART looks good. Show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema I have /dev/sda wich is 465 gb and /dev/sdb wich is 14.6 gb. USB should be 14.6 gb, so filesystem is hdd of 465gb? And for videos, I use standard ubuntu app that comes with installation, it is just called Videos.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a video issue if terminal crashes when you try to open it. Your system sounds corrupted. fsck command as mentioned is the only way to try and repair but it's not that successful. If you did not back up your root drive then a reinstall looks likely.

Comment: Show me the extensions folder, and tell me how the fsck went.

Answer (score -1):

Your HDD START data looks OK, other than being slower than normal to start.

There could be two separate issues, and these issues are different enough that I suspect that is the case.

This test will quickly show if you are missing codecs you need to play video with the Totem Video Player AKA the Video app.

Install [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) from the Ubuntu Software app or with

```
sudo apt update && sudo snap install vlc
```

When installation completes, open VLC, click on Files, navigate to a video file, select it and run it.

If it misbehaves, copy a video file under 1GB on the USB drive, then restart VLC, navigate to the USB drive, and play that file.